# Displaying different content for logged in users and storing it

Tags: php, html, authorization

I would like to know a good way to display content for logged-in users and where to store it.

My current way of doing it: storing different text and div blocks in an array and using a function that determines if a user is logged in. For example (Pseudo code):

**HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
</head>
<body>

<h1> <?= authContent("heading"); ?> </h1>
<p> <?= authContent("paragraph"); ?> </p>

</body>
</html>
```

**PHP Function:**

```
function authContent($type) {
    $loggedInContent = ["heading" => "you are logged in", "paragraph" => "logged in paragraph"];
    $notLoggedInContent = ["heading" => "you are not logged in", "paragraph" => "not logged in paragraph"];

// isLoggedIn() - function that returns true or false if user is logged in, checks session variable
if (isLoggedIn()) {
   return $loggedInContent[$type];
} else {
   return $notLoggedInContent[$type];
}

}
```

So this is a pseudo-code of what I'm doing right now, it works if the only thing that is being displayed is simple text, but what if I wanted to change the whole div block, whole style, or something similar like that? How can I store all different "displays" for logged-in/ not logged-in? if I pasted in array long div block with a lot of HTML it wouldn't look good or "nice". How to display it all instead of putting one function name in every place that I need dynamic change?
I understand that my best shot is to do OOP or to use some templating engine but because I'm a beginner I would like to do this properly in a functional way of programming, **for learning purposes**.

So the main things I would like to know:

1. How to store text and different HTML in an easy-to-read and reuse way (let's say if we had dozens of different HTML and text to swap around).
2. Display it dynamically in an easy-to-read and reuse way.

And I would love to see someone answering with the way they do it in their own projects, that would help me a lot.

Comment: What you are describing is a CMS. For a given URL and some context (user logged in, browser’s language, etc.) you want to have different results shown. Swapping things one-to-one is trivial, just a database/array with all known possibilities, possibly also with a "default". If an area can have custom HTML, like a table for one user and an image for another, that gets much more complicated. Do you store HTML in the CMS, or a meta language like Markdown?

Comment: That's the point, i don't know where should I store it, for most readable and properly acceptable way. Should I store it in array, database. When that is solved is there a better way (without template engine or lol, for learning) to display it dynamically without using my shown function?

Comment: I would say that the most common way to store this kind of information is in a database. If you keep it in an array, only you the programmer can edit it. If you keep it in a database, you the programmer can build an interface for other people to edit it. In my experience, it is rare for a single URL to be vastly different between two contexts. Parts will change, but the whole is very similar. This means that your template for that URL is consistent, and you have "regions" that change. You can give these regions names, associate them with the URL and store that in the database.

Comment: Also, building a CMS as a learning project is a fairly large task. There isn't really a right, wrong, proper or acceptable way, either. Just get something working (like you have), and then evolve it slightly, making sure it still works. You will usually find growing pains. For instance, 2 URLs is easy to update, but 100 might need a new paradigm. Same with 2 users versus 100 users. And once you get to binary content (images and files) you will find another pain point that even the modern CMSs don't do a perfect job with, either.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try with DB, by the way, the "without template engine or lol" in my comment part the "lol" meant OOP, for some reason phone auto-corrected it to "lol".